# Forecasting in R with ets() and auto.arima produces a straight line

Tags: r, forecasting

I struggle to understand why my forecasts produce a straight line. Thanks for your help.

```
bac_ts <- s.ts(read.csv('BAC.csv'), start= 2016-08-16, frequency = 252)
uni_bac_ts <- bac_ts[,9]
fit <- ets(uni_bac_ts)
fc <- forecast(fit, h=100)
autoplot(fc)
```

[image]

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) I can see a call to `autoplot()`: what is the role of `auto.arima`? What do you expect but a straight line and areas of confidence? (You *should* follow the hint and *enter an image description*!)

Comment: Thanks Uwe. I found Rob Hyndman's post about seasonality (frequency) which helped me understand this. I was trying to forecast stock performance using 252 as frequency because I thought a year is the cycle and there were 252 observations during a year. Changing the frequency to 1 (i.e. there is no seasonality) created a nice saw-edged line.

Comment: `found Rob Hyndman's post … Changing … created a nice saw-edged line` consider answering your own post (with an "after"-image to go with the "before" from the question, preferrably).

Comment: I am suffering a similar fate with Amazon Forecast. Has this been resolved?